# Joomla 3.2 not load user info

Tags: joomla

I use this code:

```
 $usuario=getJoomUser();
 $username=strtolower($usuario['username']);
 $name=$usuario['name'];
if ($usuario['id']== 0)

{
  echo "$name";
  print "No estas logueado en el sistema";

}   

else

{
```

The code works fine but not with some computers. Joomla load fine the user and his password but not my code in PHP. However, if I use that information in other computers works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

My function is:

```
function getJoomUser() {
   error_reporting(1);
   define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
   define( 'DS', '/' );
   define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . DS . 'Joomla3.2.3' );

   if(is_file(JPATH_BASE .DS.'configuration.php')) {
      require_once(JPATH_BASE .DS.'configuration.php');
   } else {
      echo "Could not locate configuration.php <br />";
   }
   if(is_file(JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes/defines.php')) {
      require_once(JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php');
   } else {
      echo "Could not locate defines.php <br />";
   }
   if(is_file(JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes/framework.php')) {
      require_once(JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php');
   } else {
      echo "Could not locate framework.php<br />";
   }
   if(is_file(JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php')) {
      require_once(JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php');
   } else {
      echo "Could not locate factory.php<br />";
   }


   $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
   $user = JFactory::getUser();   
   $userData['username'] = $user->username;
   $userData['name'] = $user->name;
   $userData['id'] = $user->id;
   $userData['email'] = $user->email;
   $userData['groups'] = $user->groups;

   return $userData;
}
?>
```

I have tried with the option -->guest and the problem continues. The key is: That happens in some pcs and I try to sign in with these user's data in my computer or another computer works fine.
I tried without to call a function and remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got `getJoomUser` from but to get the user object, you need to use this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

You can then do what you wish like so:

```
if ($user['id'] == 0){    
    print "No estas logueado en el sistema";   
}   
else{
    echo $user->username;
}
```

Comment: It's the same code than me. The only thing is I call a function.

Comment: @Zunzunm3 - When you ay it doesn't work on some computers, what do you mean exactly? You just get no data? Have you tried `var_dump($user);` on the computer that doesn't work to see what it returns? Do you get any errors on the other computers? If not then try turning error reporting on. There is nothing that a computer should be doing to manipulate the way PHP works

Comment: Parameters. I have found info about this and the problem could be I use wrapper iframe. How could I pasa the info from joomla to wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I have update to 3.3.6 and the problem continues.

On Internet Explorer, activating compatibility view works fine. WRONG

I will change to drupal...

Thanks